# How do i redirect to a GET request from a POST request on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook, fbml, facebook-graph-api

i am writing an FBML app on facebook hosted in GAE. Facebook will talk to your hosted app only vai POST (im sure this is the cause, but please do correct me if i'm wrong). So im faced with the issue that inside of my POST method, i need to redirect to facebook OAuth authroize URL. But i can only send a GET request. How can i do that? At the moment i'm doing

```
class OauthHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    # blablablab
    request.redirect(oauth_uri)
```

Which is wrong since the oauth_uri is only responding to GET. Further more, OAuth will redirect back to my redirect handler through GET, but i cant! i can only do post. So i'm confused.

ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. request.redirect will result in a GET to the oauth_uri. Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: klausbyskov, Right now, im getting a "not a proper URL" error, i'mi assumign it has to do with the confusion of get/post. no?, i'm not at home now to past the exact error, but i probably should.

Answer (score 0):

"Further more, OAuth will redirect back to my redirect handler through GET, but i cant! i can only do post. So i'm confused."

Is there a reason you can't add this to your handler? 
  def get(self):
    self.post()

It's what we've been doing for all our handlers.